# Porting Regex from Python to C++: Unexpected character in brace expression

Tags: c++, regex

Porting some code from Python 3 to C++, I'm wondering where the difference are between those two regex's. More specifically, how can I correctly port regex rules defined in Python to valid C++?

#### Python 3:

```py
import re
a = r"(- ?([^-]+(?:-={[^-]+-?$)?))$"
for b in re.findall(a, "foobar-test123"):
    print(b)
```

prints: `('-test123', 'test123')`

#### C++

```
std::regex("(- ?([^-]+(?:-={[^-]+-?$)?))$");
```

`Unexpected character in brace expression.`

Sorry in advance for the beginner question.

Comment: The pattern looks the same. Though, while the pattern is the same, perhaps C++ code that you haven't shown us is not the same.

Comment: Just escape `{`: `std::regex rx("(- ?([^-]+(?:-=\\{[^-]+-?$)?))$");`, see [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/73GALn)

Comment: Python 3 and C++ use different regular expression engines.  Lots of similarities, but also many disparities.

Comment: It's clearly the `{` character that's causing this, and a quick look around suggests that Python doesn't treat this character specially. Is this trying to literally match the `{` character?  It appears that the C++ regex package *does* treat this as special, so you may need to escape it:  `\\{`

Comment: Escaping with double quotes ```\\``` was indeed the correct approach. I previously had tried only one ```\```. Thank you.